# What are other phrases for "full of information"?

Tags: phrases

I'm thinking of the following:

- info-packed / information-packed
- knowledge-packed

I guess these are grammatically acceptable but probably there are better choices.

Comment: Those are adjectives. What are they describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Informative
- Enlightening
- Informational
- Illuminating
- Instructional
- Jam-packed with info/information
- Bursting with info
- Overflowing with info
- Rammed with facts

Answer (score 1):

The best choice depends on where you want to use but these are some of the words and phrases with similar meanings:

- contains information
- filled with information
- lots of information
- packed with information
- rich in information
- wealth of information